# Error in copying two data files in data 3 in c using command line argument

Tags: c, file, copy, fopen, eof

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2jfe.png)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void mergeFiles(FILE *file1, FILE *file2, FILE *file3)
{
    int num;
    while(fscanf(file1,"%d",&num)!=EOF)
    {
        fprintf(file3,"%d\n",&num);
    }
    while(fscanf(file2,"%d",&num)!=EOF)
    {
        fprintf(file3,"%d",&num);
    }
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    if(argc!=4) {
        printf("Usage : %s<data1><data2><data>\n",argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    FILE *file1=fopen(argv[1],"r");
    FILE *file2=fopen(argv[2],"r");
    FILE *file3=fopen(argv[3],"w");
    if(file1==NULL || file2==NULL || file3==NULL){
        fprintf("Error Opening files\n");
        return 1;
    }
    merge files(file1,file2,file3);
    printf("Merged content written to %s\n",argv[3]);
    fclose(file1);
    fclose(file2);
    fclose(file3);
    return 0;
    
}
```

What error is in this code?
Error in copying two data files in data 3 in c using command line argument

1. Open file1.txt and file2.txt in read mode.
2. Open file3.txt in write mode.
3. Run a loop to one by one copy characters of file1.txt to file3.txt.
4. Run a loop to one by one copy characters of file2.txt to file3.txt.
5. Close all files.

Comment: Please provide all textual information as text, not as picture of text. I'd like to copy paste the relevant part of the error message, the one which you ignore or missed when you read the error messages as input for your debugging.

Comment: The compiler aleeady shows the obvious errors. First fix them. Then you claim to read and write characters but you read and write integers. You also do not handle the case where `fscanf` fails because it finds something that is not a number. It will return `0` the, causing infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

I think the main problems you encounter are the following:

1. In the mergeFiles function, you pass the address of the local variable 'num' to fprintf instead of the value it contains after calling fscanf (that requires '&num' because fscanf scan the file, decode the number and store it into the respective variable passed as pointer). fprintf requires the value stored into the variable so change '&num' in 'num' and try again.
2. In the main function, when you invoke mergeFiles be sure to write 'mergeFiles' and not 'merge files' because the second is not the function name (maybe a typographical error).
3. The error you get by the compiler is caused by missing file pointer that fprintf needs to know where write, then change that line with 'fprintf(stderr, "error: ...")' for example.